# Bean IO: Date MMM in CAPS doesn't parse

Tags: java, spring, parsing, datetime, bean-io

I have a date `"28NOV2015"` which is `ddMMMyyyy` where `MMM` is in upper case

```
<field name="BirthDate" type="date" format="ddMMMyyyy"/>
```

Getting below error when date is parsed

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Date] for value '28NOV2015'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Solving it via Taking it as string & then cast would be obvious & had already done it.

Is there Any way where I can directly parse it.

Comment: Can you post how you're declaring your `CustomDateFormat`? Either the XML or the Java config.

Comment: I use BeanIO which actually matches CSV to POJO. I havent use CustomDateFormat. This date is actually present in raw format.

Comment: Which version of BeanIO are you using?

Comment: `BeanIO 2.1.0` & `Java 1.8`

Answer (score 0):

You must set shortWeekdays however you will receive in your file and overwrite the DateTypeHandler to your the customized SimpleDateFormat

```
public class MyCustomDateFormatHandler extends DateTypeHandler {

    String[] capitalDays = {
        "", "SUN", "MON",
        "TUE", "WED", "THU",
        "FRI", "SAT"
    };

    @Overwrite
    protected DateFormat createDateFormat() {
            if (this.pattern == null) {
                return createDefaultDateFormat();
            }

            symbols = new DateFormatSymbols(this.locale);
            symbols.setShortWeekdays(capitalDays);
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(this.pattern, symbols);;
            df.setLenient(this.lenient);
            if (this.timeZone != null) {
                df.setTimeZone(this.timeZone);
            }
            return df;
        }

}
```

And use that

```
<typeHandler name="myCustomDateFormatHandler" class="MyCustomDateFormatHandler" />

<field name="BirthDate" type="date" format="ddMMMyyyy" typeHandler="myCustomDateFormatHandler"/>
```